# How to run multiple firefox browser parallely having different proxy in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

The code is given Below , where it is launching three firefox browser
   , all browser has different proxy settings. Using watir how launch all three browser same time using tread in watir???

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'rautomation'
require './CLReport.class'
require 'win32ole'
# TO INITIATE FIRST FIREFOX BROWSER
# THE PROXY DATA CAN BE parameterized from Excel sheet
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'myproxy.com:8080', :ssl =>      'myproxy.com:8080'
$b1 = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
$b1.goto("https://google.com")

# TO INITIATE SECOND FIREFOX BROWSER
# THE PROXY DATA CAN BE parameterized from Excel sheet
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'myproxy.com:8081', :ssl =>      'myproxy.com:8081'
$b2 = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
$b2.goto("https://google.com")

# TO INITIATE THORD FIREFOX BROWSER
# THE PROXY DATA CAN BE parameterized from Excel sheet
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'myproxy.com:8082', :ssl =>     'myproxy.com:8082'
$b3 = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
$b3.goto("https://google.com")
```

Now my question is how to join $b1,$b2,$b3 in a single browser using thread so that 
    only $browser.link(:text, "form application")click should work for all three browser parallely insted of writing

```
$b1.link(:text, "form application").click
$b2.link(:text, "form application").click    
$b3.link(:text, "form application").click
```

i.e single line of code work work in three firefox browser same time parallely.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because $b1,$b2,$b3 are instances of different browser,You can not make them equal.What are you doing is right. Or You can do some thing like that.

```
array = [$b1,$b2,$b3]
array.each { |browser|
browser.link(:text, "form application").click
}
```